# How Do I Use Axios to Post Form Data?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am working on a project with a springboot backend and Vue frontend. Right now I am able to GET a list of products from my database. I can GET the list and display it on a page but I am trying to use a form to POST a new product. I was able to successfully setup a POST method but can only send hard coded info.

With Vuex should I be updating the state and then posting or just use the action to post the form data to my backend directly? What is best practice and how do I do it?

Note the areas I am running into are the "data: function()" in the component and the "submitProduct" action.

This is my Vue Component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <br/>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="product in products">{{product.name}} - {{product.description}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <form id="newproductform" @submit="submitProduct">
      <h4>New Product</h4>
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name: {{name}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="name">
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="description">Description: {{description}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description" v-model="description">
      </p>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState, mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Products',
  data: function () {
    return {
      name: '',
      description: ''
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      products: state => state.products
    }),

    ...mapGetters({
    })
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      loadProducts: 'loadProducts',
      submitProduct: 'submitProduct'
    })
  },

  created () {
    this.loadProducts()
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

This is my store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {},

  state: { // data
    products: []
  },

  getters: { // computed properties
    // getter (state, getters)
    allProducts: state => state.products
  },

  actions: { // actions store methods
    // action (context)
    loadProducts: function ({commit}) {
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:8081/product')
        .then(request => request.data._embedded.product)
        .then(product => {
          commit('setProductToState', product)
        })
    },

    addNewProductToState: function ({commit}) {
      commit('setNewProductToState')
    },

    submitProduct: function () {
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:8081/product', {
          name: '' + this.data.name,
          description: '' + this.data.description
        })
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    // mutation (state, payload)
    setProductToState (state, product) {
      state.products = product
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

1. You are using the `data` object of your component as models for your form, but you are never mutating your state with the changed values
2. You should make use of the context passed to each action inside the Vuex store (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html):

Change this:

```
submitProduct: function () {   
    axios.post('http://localhost:8081/product', {
      name: '' + this.data.name,
      description: '' + this.data.description
    }) 
}
```

To this:

```
submitProduct: function (context) {
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:8081/product', {
      name: '' + context.store.name,
      description: '' + context.store.description
    })
}
```

I would probably also suggest to not define component specific actions inside your store. Those action should be used for store related actions.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have tried a few times to update the state but am having trouble conceptualizing it. Would it be best practice to update my product state with the new product or create a new state for the newproduct?

Comment: The question is: do you really need the store? Do you need to access the products from other parts of the app?

Comment: I am not sure. I'm still learning and experimenting with vue. I may decide I need it in the store later on or I may need something else in the store later on. I've been stuck on being able to post a new product to my DB using the form data.

Comment: Ok let me ask differently: why dont you Post from the component itself and then only commit/add the new product to the store by commiting a mutation? I am not at the PC at the moment, but i could add more Info to my answer tomorrow

Comment: I can try posting from the component itself but there is no need to commit a mutation to the store because I am getting the products from my DB on created. Problem is, I need to figure out how to post the form data regardless of where it is.

Comment: Also, If I do the post directly from the component I would have to import axios to every component I do a post in. I would rather have those API methods in a central location. Maybe that's not best practice but its easier for me to organize my project.

Comment: Okay then the store is the right place. You need to commit the product to the store and inside that mutation you Post to your database and in success also mutate your store.

Comment: For your other question: you can add axios to your vue instance and use it everywhere. For example: https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Okay. That;s great to know about Axios. Now I just need to figure out how to commit the new product to the store and post.... learning... I appreciate your help!

Comment: Good answer but it also needs the `name` and `description` added to the initial `state` in order for them to be reactive

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.

Just had to do this to the action

```
submitProduct: function () {
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value
  const description = document.getElementById('description').value
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:8081/product', {
      name: name,
      description: description
    })
}
```